# tensorflow fined tune model Fast-RCNN does not show bounding box

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I fined tuned both SSD Mobilenet and Fast-RCNN on the same dataset. Both models ran training and inference without any error. But Fast-RCNN fined tuned model does not show any bounding boxes. So I tried with one training image to see if the trained model is able to draw a bbox on an image that it was trained from. But it shows nothing. Where should I start looking for debugging ?

Comment: tf-object-detection-api uses Faster-RCNN. Are you using a self-implemented Fast-RCNN code?